How The PATH Environment Variable is Configured for PySpark
I would like to run PySpark with Jupyter Notebook on my Windows 10 laptop. I installed Python (3.9.13), Java (1.8.0_202), and Spark (3.5.1). Then, I installed Jupyter Notebook and PySpark (3.5.1).
I tried a test first. In the Command Prompt window, I entered the command pyspark to open the PySpark shell. Then, I tested some simple PySpark code. However, I could only do this in the Spark bin directory where pyspark.cmd is located (c:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\bin). In other directories, the command pyspark couldn't be recognized (Error: \Microsoft was unexpected at this time) unless I entered the command with the full path, c:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\bin\pyspark.


I tried to check if I configured the PATH correctly. I didn't find anything wrong. %SPARK_HOME%\bin is set to c:\Spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\bin, which is included in the %PATH%. Are there any problems? Please help.

Later, I tried to run pyspark in Jupyter and got an exception at the call to getOrCreate().  The exception: gateway process exited before sending its port number. Don't know if the two issues are related.  Would like to resolve the one above first.  Thanks for help!

I know you said you are more interested in the issue above the Jupyter one, however, I know Jupyter better. For the Jupyter part, see this thread here.
